# FOV not matching projection matrix

Tags: python, camera

I'm trying to write custom OpenGL renderer that produces the exact same images as blender. However I struggle with getting camera right.

I duplicated [this code](https://github.com/martijnberger/blender/blob/c359343f8dae6689c955dc1fa700cb26f6cd2e95/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/camera.c#L387) and I managed to produce the exact same matrix as in `calc_matrix_camera`

```
render = bpy.context.scene.render
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
proj_matrix = bpy.context.scene.camera.calc_matrix_camera(depsgraph,x=render.resolution_x,y=render.resolution_y,scale_x=render.pixel_aspect_x,scale_y=render.pixel_aspect_y)
```

I get the model-view matrix identical as in `bpy.context.scene.camera.matrix_world` but for testing purposes I always place camera at the origin point with no rotation (so model-view matrix is the identity matrix). However I still cannot get the renderings right. What I find suspicious is that

```
bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].angle_y
```

returns a different value from

```
2.0*math.atan( 1.0/proj_matrix[1][1])
```

([explanation of math here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182845/field-of-view-aspect-ratio-view-matrix-from-projection-matrix-hmd-ost-calib)). I suspect there is some extra logic that I'm not taking into account. How do I get aspect ratio and fov from blender? Which of those values is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed some extra logic. In general you should use `camera.angle` and take the settings under *Camera Properties > Camera > Sensor Fit* into account.

Lets set first

```
camera = bpy.data.cameras['Camera']
aspect = render.resolution_x / render.resolution_y
```

If the *Sensor Fit* is set to *Horizontal* you'll have (equaling `angle_x`)

```
camera.angle = 2.0 * math.atan(aspect / proj_matrix[1][1])
```

If it's set to *Vertical* you'll get (equaling `angle_y`)

```
camera.angle = 2.0 * math.atan( 1.0/ proj_matrix[1][1])
```

Finally, if it's set to *Auto* it depends on the `aspect` ratio:

If `aspect > 1` then `camera.angle = camera.angle_x = 2.0 * math.atan(aspect / proj_matrix[1][1])`

If `aspect < 1` then `camera.angle = camera.angle_x = 2.0 * math.atan(1.0 / proj_matrix[1][1])`

If `aspect == 1` then `camera.angle = camera.angle_x = 2.0 * math.atan(aspect / proj_matrix[1][1]) = 2.0 * math.atan(1.0 / proj_matrix[1][1])`

For an in-depth explanation on what Blender is doing under the hood see my [answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300659/how-to-specify-specific-x-and-y-fov-angles-for-a-camera-in-blender-3-6).